# RSS does not validate properly

Tags: feeds

I am trying to generate an RSS feed, but it does not validate. I googled around and found [RSS Feed does not validate using Views RSS module](https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/86169/rss-feed-does-not-validate-using-views-rss-module), but unfortunately it's for Drupal 7, while I am using Drupal 8.4.4.

What a similar method for Drupal 8 would be? The XML I get has an empty line before `<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>`, which I believe it's the main problem.

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="utf-8"?>
  <rss version="2.0" xml:base="https://example.com/feeds.xml" xmlns:dc="http://purl.org/dc/elements/1.1/" xmlns:content="http://purl.org/rss/1.0/modules/content/" xmlns:foaf="http://xmlns.com/foaf/0.1/" xmlns:og="http://ogp.me/ns#" xmlns:rdfs="http://www.w3.org/2000/01/rdf-schema#" xmlns:schema="http://schema.org/" xmlns:sioc="http://rdfs.org/sioc/ns#" xmlns:sioct="http://rdfs.org/sioc/types#" xmlns:skos="http://www.w3.org/2004/02/skos/core#" xmlns:xsd="http://www.w3.org/2001/XMLSchema#">
    <channel>
      <title>Title</title>
      <link>https://example.com/feeds.xml</link>
      <language>en</language>

      <item>
        <title>UAE Lenders Upbeat as Growth Prospects Surge</title>
        <link>https://halaltimes.com/uae-lenders-upbeat-growth-prospects-surge</link>
        <description>  &lt;img src=&quot;/sites/default/files/styles/large/public/Article/growth-prospects-surge-in-uae.jpg?itok=VEwWB-9R&quot; width=&quot;480&quot; height=&quot;320&quot; alt=&quot;&quot; typeof=&quot;Image&quot; class=&quot;image-style-large&quot; /&gt;
```

Answer (score 0):

Do you have a template for views-view-rss.html.twig in your theme folder? 
Try enabling the Twig debug feature if you are not sure.

The default one in core/modules/views/templates works properly (same core version).